# Apache ProxyPass Virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, virtualhost, mod-proxy, httpd.conf

I'm trying to do a similar setup to the one discussed in [this older thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/273679/redirecting-to-other-internal-servers-based-on-sub-domain).  I've enabled the proxy_module, proxy_connect_module, proxy_http_module, and rewrite_module.  It worked, but now when I go to domain.com it takes me to the ipcamera.  I tried adding another virtual host with ServerName domain.com pointing to localhost, but that just makes the page hang.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ipcam.domain.com

    ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyErrorOverride On                       
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.123/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.123/
    <Location />
    Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com

    ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyErrorOverride On                       
    ProxyPass / http://localhost/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/
    <Location />
    Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have NamevirtualHost *:80 somewhere in your config?
Secondly: Proxying to Localhost is pointless, as that means proxying to itself. I would suggest you revert to your previously working config for domain.com and put that first in your config, and ipcamera.domain.com second.

Comment: And give us the output of httpd -S as well... That is more or less mandatory when trying to debug virtual host problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

domain.com should be hosted on the same server ?
You are proxying to the same server (localhost being localhost), so you get an infinite loop?
Remove from second virtualhost the proxy stuff , and configure DocumentRoot etc .

Comment: After fiddling around with it some more I was able to get it working doing exactly that.  Thanks for the help.

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName     domain.com
    DocumentRoot "www/mainserver"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername      ipcam.domain.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass       /   http://192.168.1.123/
    ProxyPassReverse    /   http://192.168.1.123/

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>